# do theses phrases really differ?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

unfortunately I have no context to provide, But as a learner I've been thinking a lot about adjective positions and trying to understand its usage. One case sticks to mind:

1. "a divided house"
2. "a house divided"

My instinct tells me it differ somehow I can't explain, do they really differ?

Comment: A recent question, which has been closed, mentioned these phrases and I commented - We would normally speak of 'a divided house' unless we are saying 'a house [which is] divided into flats/apartments'. However, the expression _a house divided_ is familiar to many people from the Bible verse Mark 3:25 "And if a house be divided against itself, that house cannot stand" (KJV). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln%27s_House_Divided_Speech

Comment: I might regard a 'divided house' without any context as a dwelling house partitioned into separate apartments.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, I think that too, But when comes to "house divided" I don't know what to think. this without context which is the case to force your thinking. The reason I come with this question and though about those exact words: "house divided" is to reason on future similar cases.

Comment: "A house divided into three apartments" is easy to understand, likewise 'the Socialist Party is a house divided on the matter of taxation of higher incomes'. The bare phrase without context is ambiguous. This is the case with many phrases in English, where only context clarifies meaning.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, "the Socialist Party is a house divided on the matter of taxation of higher incomes" that helped me a lot, if you let me I wanto to ask if similarly to this example of "socialist part is a house divided...." example I can say: "the governor wants house available to homeless people"?? it omes to mind "house divided" has same structure of "house available " right?

Comment: Henryke, are you the same person who asked the earlier question, or have you both been studying the same material? _Wants house available_ is not correct grammar, nor would it be with any other adjective. You have to say _the governor wants a/the house to be [made] available..._.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I've browsed through some question on stackexchange and reading the "house divided" one it got me thinking if "house divede"  is possible why not "house available"?? it seems to have same structure and it led me very curisou about that

Comment: Ah, I  see. We don't normally put the adjective after the noun unless it's part of a phrase such as _a house [which is] divided into apartments_. As I explained above, the expression _a house divided_ is a special case because of the Biblical reference and its use in a famous speech by Abraham Lincoln, referring to serious differences of opinion in an organisation which is supposed to be unified.